# Why am I getting an array of nulls instead of an array of zeroes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following code (vue 3):

```
    const salesTotal = computed(() => {
      let totalSalesAmount = new Array(numberOfPeriods).fill(0);
      return totalSalesAmount;
    });

    const cogsTotal = computed(() => {
      let totalCOGSAmount = new Array(numberOfPeriods).fill(0);
      return totalCOGSAmount;
    });

    const grossMarginTotal = computed(() => {
      let grossMarginAmount = [];
      for (let k = 0; k < numberOfPeriods; k++) {
        grossMarginAmount[k] = salesTotal[k] + cogsTotal[k];
      }
      return grossMarginAmount;
    });
```

numberOfPeriods is 5.
I'm getting `[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]` for both `salesTotal` and `cogsTotal` when I print them, but `[ null, null, null, null, null ]` for `grossMarginTotal`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, correct code is as follows:
`grossMarginAmount[k] = salesTotal.value[k] + cogsTotal.value[k];`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).